# Problem with understanding the definition of electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, conventions, integration

Here is the definition I know:

$V(\vec r)-V(\vec r_0)=\int_{\vec r_0}^{\vec r} -\vec E \cdot\vec dr$

I have lots of problems with this topic. How can I choose the starting point? and does it matter where? I see in books that sometimes we can write  $\vec r_0=\infty$ so that $V(\vec r_0)=0$, because for a finite charge, the potential should be $0$ very far from it, because a charge in that distance would have $0$ energy because the force acting on it is $0$

Also sometimes the function in the integral diverges  if I plug $\infty$.

Edit-
Here is a problem on that:

Given E field in spherical coordinates:

$\vec E(r)=\frac{kQ}{r}\hat r$

I can write $V(r)-V(\infty)=\int_{\infty}^{\vec r} -\frac{kQ}{r}dr=-kQ[\ln{r}-\ln\infty]$. Then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electrostatic field is defined as a gradient of a scalar potential:
$$\vec E(\vec r)=-\nabla V(\vec r).$$
Thus there is considerable freedom in how one might a scalar potential for any given electric field. One might add any constant $V_0$ to it without changing the physics one bit:
$$V^\prime(\vec r)=V(\vec r)+V_0\implies\vec E^\prime(\vec r)=-\nabla(V(\vec r)+V_0)=-\nabla V(\vec r)=\vec E(\vec r).$$
This freedom of choice can be used to the advantage, i.e. one can use it to get rid of terms like $V(\vec r_0)$ For example, as you note in  your post,
$$V(\vec r)=V(\vec r_0)+\int_{\vec r_0}^{\vec r}-\vec E(\vec r)\cdot d\vec r;$$
however, on may write:
$$V^\prime (\vec r)=V(\vec r)+V_0=V(\vec r_0)+\int_{\vec r_0}^{\vec r}-\vec E(\vec r)\cdot d\vec r.$$ Note that with the modified potential and setting $V_0=V(\vec r_0)$, the pesky $V(\vec r_0)$ is cancelled out without making any assumption that $\vec r_0\rightarrow +\infty$. Physically this is tantamount to the statement that only potential *differences* are relevant to physics, and not the absolute value of the potential at any given point, one is free to choose any point to be the "zero point", and measure the potential at all other points relative to it. For practical purposes it is often convenient to choose this point at infinity, however, it is not at all necessary.

The quantity in the integrand is the electric field $\vec E(\vec r)$ and it is difficult to imagine how any finite charge distribution can give rise to an electric field that does not diminish at infinity. Thus, it is difficult to comment on your specific problem in this regard without an explicit example of a supposed divergent field $\vec E$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite understand these expressions :$V^\prime(\vec r)=V(\vec r)+V_0$. You are basicly saying I can always choose the arbitrary point at infinity and say the potential there is $0$? And if its infinite charge I can't choose the point on infinity, so I choose other point and call it $0$?

Comment: See my edit for example of potential at infinity

Comment: @Dor For the example given, i.e. $\vec E(\vec r)$, the potential does not diverge if you plug in $\infty$,e.g. $\int_{\infty}^R -\vec E(\vec r)\cdot d\vec r+\int_R^r -{kQ\over r}\hat r\cdot d\vec r=-\int_R^r {kQ\over r}\; dr=-{kQ}[\ln(r)-\ln(R)]=kQ\ln[{R\over r}].$ The first integral disappears because $\vec E(\vec r)$ is everywhere zero over the interval $(R,\infty)$.

Comment: @Dor So, $V(r)-V(\infty)=\int_R^r -{kQ\over r}\hat r\cdot d\vec r=V(r)-V(R)=kQ\ln[{R\over r}]$ choose $V(\infty)=V(R)=0$ so that you have $V(r)=kQ\ln[{R\over r}], \forall r\leq R$ and $V(r)=0, \forall r\gt R$.

Comment: So I have to split because the field jumps at $r=R$. I can't just integrate the whole space because of that jump right? that's the reason I would get $\ln{\infty}$.
What if the field I mentioned is for the whole space? (without zeroes) How can I express $V(r)-V(\infty)$? that would require putting $\infty$ in the $\ln$

Comment: @Dor Exactly right, you must split the integration because you have that jump. Okay, if the field is given by ${kQ\over r} \forall r\in(0,\infty)$ then, $\int_r^\infty -{kQ\over r^\prime}\; dr^\prime=-kQ\ln(r^\prime)|_r^\infty=-kQ(\lim\limits_{r^\prime\rightarrow\infty}\ln(r^\prime)-\ln(r))=\infty.$ Thus, the integral diverges. Sometimes it takes clever manipulations to get rid of these infinities. What kind charge density is giving rise to the field, $\vec E$?

Comment: @Dor It appears in your problem for example, that $\rho(\vec r)=Q$, i.e. a constant charge density throughout all space. Thus, it doesn't seem surprising that an infinite amount of charge gives rise to infinities. Usually we use $Q$ as a symbol or total charge, so it is odd that it appears as it does in your problem.

Comment: I think, this field (the one with the jump) can be created by a cylinder inside some conductor that covers it, and the conductor is grounded to earth

Comment: @Dor Yes, but then you would be working in cylindrical coordinates and not spherical as indicated, however, the same could be done for a ball of charge surrounded by a spherical conducting cover, and the problem would be spherical. In either case one has the "jump" and integrating without makes no physical sense to those problems.

Answer (score 2):

Potential is uniquely defined up to an *arbitrary* additive constant, so it doesn't matter which starting point you use or the value of the potential at this point. The value of the potential at any point is enough to determine the potential everywhere else.

For a charge distribution that doesn't extend to infinity, it is usually convenient to take $V(\infty) = 0$, because this is in agreement with the expression

$$ V(\mathbf r) = \iiint \frac{\rho(\mathbf r')}{4\pi\epsilon_0\lVert\mathbf r-\mathbf r'\rVert}d^3\mathbf r '$$
where $\rho$ is the charge density and the integral is over the charge distribution. If you don't take $V(\infty)=0$, $V(\infty)$ needs to be added to the right-hand side.

If the charge distribution does extend to infinity in such a way that it is not possible or useful to set $V(\infty)$ to some finite constant, you can choose the value of the potential at another point. All you are doing is choosing the value of the arbitrary constant, the definition does not change.

Comment: Excellent points about the potential for charge densities that extend to infinity. It is well known that some such integrals are divergent, e.g. potential for an infinite line of uniform charge $\rho$.   However, such a problem can be approached by considering a finite distribution $[-L,L]$, and integrating to find the potential for a point very close to the charge (ignore edges), i.e. $V_L(\vec r)$ and show that $V_L(\vec r)-2\rho\log(L)$ converges as $L\rightarrow\infty$.